# htaccess query. 2 rewrites rules for 2 home pages

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm hoping someone might be able to help with a problem I'm having due to my lack of experience and knowledge with htaccess.

What we're doing is running IP Boards forum software and wordpress both in the root directory. The IPB has the index.php file (because of having indexed url's) and the new Wordpress's index.php file has been renamed to blog.php.

At the very top of the htaccess file we've added: DirectoryIndex blog.php index.php  - so the new wordpress opens first.

The problem I'm having is trying to have 2 rewriterules in the htaccess file for the friendly urls from the forum software and also the permalinks for the new wordpress.

I can only seem to have one or the other.

Please could anyone tell me, or point me in the right direction to get both working.

This is what I'm doing so far but sadly no joy, but works fine if we remove one of the condition and rewrites.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still want an answer. Either way, if you are trying to go to two different pages you need some way of distinguishing them.

`DirectoryIndex` basically tells the default file (and order) when entering a directory. So `http://host.com/` with both `blog.php` and `index.php` in the directory will serve up `blog.php` because it is first in the list you gave the server. If there is only `index.php`, it will serve that. If neither (and you don't have anything else in the list) it will throw a 404 because no default file is found.

EDIT: it will try to list contents if not found. My bad. If you don't allow directory listing, then it will probably show an error code. To turn off directory listing look in options: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html

Your rewrite rules seem to kind of want do the same thing in a different order. If you request `http://host.com/a` and `a` is not a file or directory (according to the conditions) it will go to `index.php`.. if `index.php` doesn't exist, then it will loop until the server catches it, because you don't check that. So, that means the second set of conditions don't do anything, because either `index.php` exists or it doesn't and the next set probably won't really be reached unless it does.

You need to decide how to differentiate the two (`/blog/` for the `blog.php` and `/` for `index.php` or something) and make one of them the default. If you want to randomize it, I would suggest doing that through PHP.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

.. to redirect from root to /forums/ through htaccess try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/forums/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /forums/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Huge thank you for your reply and help. I read the links over and over but cant get the permalinks working with the mod_rewrites for the forum. We've now moved the forum into a folder names /forums/ to resolve the issue but would you know of a way we could remove /forums/ from the url?

Comment: @user1310004 I updated the answer at the bottom to show a redirect to forums, but that's not really part of the original question. Did you understand that having two default files are confusing? Which one is supposed to load and how is the server supposed to tell the difference? One should be the default for the root and the other for some other condition. That's basically what I was trying to get across.

Comment: Hi. Thanks again for your time. Yes, I understood the point you were making but I couldn't find a way to tell the server which was for the forum rewriterule (index.php) and which was for the wordpress permalinks (blog.php). So looked at another option. Ideally we want to use the opiginal with both in the root because of SEO reasons. Would you have any idea how we would go about telling the server which is which? Apologies for all the questions and lack of knowledge on this. Really appreciate your help and time.

Comment: If you are telling the server, it has to be via url or query string. you can have one as default (index.php), so when 'host.com' or 'www.host.com' or either with a slash gets entered, 'index.php' gets called. The other (blog.php) could be by a subdomain 'blog.host.com' (or another domain 'other.com'), but that can cause problems (not something that can't be worked out) if you want to call something over the other domain. The other is a separate folder `host.com/b/` or something or you can use a query string. Either way, you need some way of telling the server which file to point to.